# Classification task on boolean only features: what model/layers/activators are better?

Tags: classification, keras, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a classification model. Features are purely boolean (not binary) and are in a csv file like `1,0,1,..`
The result is an `int` within a range(0, 128).

I thought, would it make sense not to waste resources on float operations as there are no float data? What models (from Keras, if possible), types of layers, and activators are better for this task?

I'm trying this way and the results are no better than random on ~2mln samples:

```
  from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
  from keras.utils import to_categorical
  from keras.models import Sequential
  from keras.layers import Dense

  X = np.loadtxt("001_X.csv", dtype=bool)
  y = np.loadtxt("001_y.csv", dtype=int)
    
  (X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test) = train_test_split(X, y, shuffle=True, train_size=0.9)

  y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
  y_test = to_categorical(y_test)
        
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Dense(1000, input_dim=128, activation="relu"))
  ... etc...
  model.add(Dense(128, activation='softmax'))

  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics='accuracy')

  model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, callbacks=[callback], batch_size=100)
```

Anything else I can improve for better accuracy?

Comment: Do you have 128 labels/classes?

Comment: @HarshadPatil Yes. One class, 128 possible values. (The result is one int within a range(0, 128).)

Comment: So you are predicting for 128 different classes. Am I right?

Comment: @HarshadPatilI'm unsure I get the terminology right. My apologies, I'm a newbie. I'm predicting one integer (one column), which can be within the mentioned range only.

Comment: I am asking about 1. You are doing classification rt? If yes then 2. How many different values are there in the prediction column

Comment: Yes, classification. 128 different values in that column. One column to predict.

Answer (score 0):

Most architecture rely on float operations as the optimisation process requires to work with a continum of values. If you want to solve for parameters than can only take discrete values, then it's not a differentiable problem and you cant use gradient descent to optimise the network for your task.

After a quick search it seems that some people worked on creating a **Differentiable Logic Gate Networks** that allows to learn logic gate combinations to process boolean inputs :
https://github.com/Felix-Petersen/difflogic . But's it is not something very common.

If you're network does not learn anything than you may want to change your network, or try to get some insights on your problem in order to help the learning process.

Comment: I just want to use the resources wisely. If floats can't be avoided - okay, let's go with that. However, the data does not contain floats. Also, I understand/realize that prediction can say e.g. valueA probability is 0.6, valueB probability is 0.4, etc.

Comment: Indeed, most models wont return a class but rather predict a probability distribution. Then you need to choose a deicision rule in order to obtain the final class. The usual decision use is to take the class with highest predicted probabilities, but this is not the only possible choice.

Comment: Decision can be made using `argmax` or `prediction[:,1]`

Comment: Take the most probable result is not a problem, when you have a decent result. In the initial question I asked advise about model/layers type because those I'm using give really weak results. My apologies if I worded it unclear.

Answer (score 0):

As you have a lot of labels to predict. I will suggest few basic things which might improve the score or will improve the interpretability:

```py
(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test) = train_test_split(X, y, shuffle=True, train_size=0.8, stratify = y)
```

Use stratify. It will make sure that you have equal amount of labels in train and test data.

Try to balance your data by `upsampling` or `downsampling`